# filter a table with button value in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter

I want to filter a table with a button to several values in Javascript.

I used the below code but when I want filter table with a button that has several value and then do a filter on table?

```
var $rows = $('#table tbody tr');
    var val = $.trim(input).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();

    $rows.show().filter(function () {
      var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
      return !~text.indexOf(val);
    }).hide();
```

Comment: "a button that has several value". Please explain what that is about. Adding relevant HTML and showing what `input` is , and where this code is called, would all help to clarify what you are asking for.

Comment: Using the text for the button display isn't perhaps the best way to pass filtering values. I would recommend a `data-filter` attribute on the button with the values json encoded, then access them when you need to perform the filter.